# How can i solve heroku Application error?

Tags: heroku

[image][image]

*I am having a Heroku Application error. I can not find how can I solve it. or you can say to me how can i remove the whole Heroku application from my project to re-create Heroku app.
thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: "MODULE_NOT_FOUND... Cannot fine module '/app/index..js'"—is your file really called `index..js`, with two `.`s? Suspect this is just a typo in your `start` script.

Comment: Mr. Chris, thanks for your suggestion and I got my answer from your comment.  Next time i will try to upload code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: #1 Extract the more relevant words of your log and research. It is a classic error. #2 Does it at least work on your machine? #3 Share us the code